# how to install Canon mf8280cw

Tags: canon

I just aquired free Canon multifunction MF8280cw. How can I install it on ubuntu 14.04? (64bit)
When I go to printers, it offers the option of providing a PPD file, how can I find that? It does not show up on the cd that came with the printer. It is connected via the network and when I click on find printer, it finds it but doesn't have a driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [page](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF8280Cw.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Linux) offers a .zip file containing two .deb files (in the Debian folder), one for 32-bits and one for a 64-bits installation. Unzip the correct one and double-click it. You should be taken to the Software Center where you can install the driver.